# Is there a "right "way to store a String and an Integer in the same array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, typed-arrays

I think that store a String and an Integer in the same array in Java would be more efficient in some cases, but I know that Java is strongly typed.

Is there a way to do that?, If there's no, what can I do?

Comment: `Object[]`. But why do you want that?

Comment: what do you mean by more efficient? does it boost up the performance of your app?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Why do you think you need it? What do you want to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining "more efficient" usually means less storage space or less processor intensive. These are diametrically opposite goals. The challenge is balancing them.

You could use an `Object[]` type as stated before, but this would require determining the type and then casting every element to either a `String` or `Int` prior to use.

Boxing, convert to `Object` type, and unboxing, convert to original type, are 
relatively expensive operations in Java.

Possible solutions if they *must* be stored using the same array index:

- If you do not need to do further mathematical processing on the `int` items, use the `.toString()` method to convert it to a `String` and store it in an array of `String`s.
- If the number of Integer elements will be much lower than the `String`s, use the `.toString()` method to convert it to a `String` and store it in an array of `String`s. Then parse the `int`s back out using `Integer.parseInt()`.(`parseInt()` is considered a slow operation)
- If memory is not a concern, make two separate arrays of the same size, one of type `String` and another of type `int`.  Choose one to be primary(most populated). Use a flag value("" for `String` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for `int`) to indicate the result is the other type and should use the value stored in the other array. This preserves the common index at the expense of more memory used.

I would suggest rewriting the code to use two separate arrays if possible.

Comment: So, I was just thinking if I could save some lines of code storing them in the same array, now I see that is better use an array for each type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Object[]` to do this. But please don't. If you feel that you need to mix different types in a single array, maybe it's time to reconsider your design (here's an idea: convert the `String`s to `Integer`s or even `int`s before storing them). It simply isn't "right" to store such different data types in the same array.

Comment: Thanks!, Now I see that's better store them in an array for each type 

Answer (score 0):

```
    package ArrayPractice;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Question8 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the array range: ");
            int i= sc.nextInt();
            int [] data= new int[i];
            ArrayList<Object> testing= new ArrayList<>();
            Object [] demo= new Object[i];

            for (int y = 0; y < data.length; y++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the Array number: " + y);
                demo[y]= sc.next();
            }

            for(Object o: demo){
                System.out.println(o);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am taking input using scanner class and after that I have created the Array of Object type in which I am storing the values.